# Logic to detect newer version

Tags: c#

I have some code to detect if a new version is available.

There are 6 variables involved.
3 of them are your installed app version
The other 3 are the version numbers it finds from the internet update.

```
if (nMajor > nAppMajor || nMinor > nAppMinor || nBuild > nAppBuild)
        {
                //if update found:
        }
```

It has been working correctly for example from version 1.1.3 to 1.1.4
But now I am testing a version 1.2.0.

The latest public update it informs you of is 1.1.8.

If you are running version 1.2.0 (as I am as a test), it detects a newer version as it reads the 8 from 1.1.8 as a 'newer' version. I'm sure its a simple fix to get round this, but I cant work out the logic.

Comment: Hint: you only care about the minor version if the major version is the same in old and new. Same for build number and minor version

Comment: There are superior  ways to do this, f.e. the [Version-Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.7). The come with built in correct comparisons - create two instances of them, compare, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you compare any version part if bigger then the one before. Versions are *hierarchical* though, so you would need to only check the minor if the mayor is the same, and only check the build if mayor and minor are identical.

There is a dedicated Version class in the framework, see [`Version`-ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7#System_Version__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) that does all the needed comparison logic for you:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {  
        var app    = new Version(1, 1, 8);
        var online = new Version(1, 2, 0);

        Console.WriteLine(app);
        Console.WriteLine(online);
        Console.WriteLine("online newer? {0}", app < online);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.1.8
1.2.0
online newer? True
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasnt aware of this class.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few methods. You have to compare the numbers "as a whole", not as their "individual parts".

**Math**

```
if (nMajor*10000 + nMinor * 100 + nBuild >
    nAppMajor*10000 + nAppMinor*100 + nAppBuild)
```

You are comparing `(1*10000 + 2*100 + 0) = 10200` to `(1*10000 + 1*100 + 8) = 10108`. It's simple, but it works.

The caveat here, is that you can never have nAppMinor or nAppBuild be larger than 2 digits, something that is unlikely.

There are better ways to do this, but this addresses your code and logic.

Comment: Thank you, of course! I knew it would be as simple as that, but had a block.

Comment: Of note, the other answer is better. I just wanted to show you the logic.